# Get a range of dates from user in ios ... best way

Tags: ios, date, calendar, datepicker

I need to get a range of dates from the user in ios. Are there any third party libs to help with this. Ex: http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/selection/calendar.html. The above would be nice, but I can't find anything like this. Also, I've looked into date pickers and the libraries from this stackoverflow post:[iPhone - Where can I find a custom Calendar-like date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064777/iphone-where-can-i-find-a-custom-calendar-like-date-picker)

Preferably, getting the dates would be gui-based so I wouldn't have to do as much of sanitizing of input.

This seems like it would be a fairly common chore, so I'm surprised that I can't find any info on how other people do it.

Comment: Does a `UIDatePicker` and complementary table view with Start/End Date rows not meet your needs? Similar to how Calendar allows you to input a start and end time for an event.

Comment: have you searched cocoacontrols website?

Comment: @ppilone though not ideal, I have tried to do something like the calendar app, but where you could display the data and search it in one screen. Did not go well. If you press search fast enough, it looks like the date picker's date gets truncated.

Comment: You can make a customized Calender using UITableView, it will be a better to implement